# how change package name in intellij android project?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Just getting started with Android development using `intellij` and Stack Overflow.

I am looking for change the package name of my project , I have one solution and want to use it in two projects with some change and the new one.

for example in my current this is my package

> com.example.test1

i want to make a cope of my project and change the package of it into

> com.example.test2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on pacakage name select refactor and rename packagename

Answer (score 2):

> Right Click -> Refactor -> Rename

Answer (score 2):

in intellij idea ,
1.

```
first of all, you should change the package name in manifest file
```

,

 
2.

```
then go to gen->"com.example.urpackagenam" and right click on that package folder,select refactor->rename->renamepackage , and rename your package ,
```

 
3.

```
then click "do refactor" in menue bar in bottom.
```

 
4.

```
after appearing a dialog ,select "load file system changes".
```


that's it.